# Xfce 4 desktop zooming function conflicts with Chrome

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I upgraded to Xubuntu 18.04 from 14.04 recently. I used to zoom in and out with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ mouse wheel and it works on the new system well most of the time. But when the mouse cursor is within the Chrome web page view port, it will scroll the page while zooming. It seems that Chrome still captures the input events even if I set the key binding.

This issue doesn't only occur with Chrome but also with Mousepad, but not with Firefox. I don't know which application is causing the problem: Xfce or Chrome?

- Xfwm4 version: 4.12.4
- Chrome version: 68.0.3440.106

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to fix with the following JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  if (e.altKey === true) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}, { passive: false });
```

To make this a global fix in Chrome, it would need to be incorporated into a Chrome Extension. You need a file containing the above code snippet, such as `content.js`, and a `manifest.json` file like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Scroll Wheel Mod",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": [ "content.js" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Once you have this, it's just a few simple steps in Chrome:

- Go to `chrome://extensions/`
- Enable `Developer Mode`
- Choose `Load Unpacked`
- Choose the local directory where you created the files